# Histeq matlab not working

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, histogram

I want to histogram equalization for SPOT5 image. Im trying to do with `histeq` command. Why isn't this working?

This is my input and error:

```
>>I = imread('C:\Users\windows 8\Downloads\ori.tif');

>>imshow( I(:,:,1:3) )
```

> Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 17% 
>   In imuitools\private\initSize at 72In imshow at 283

```
>> J = histeq(I);
```

> Error using histeq
>   Expected input number 1, I, to be two-dimensional.

I am still new to [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab). I really
appreciate some help. Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems like `histeq` works only for grayScale images. yours is a RGB 3D image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is happening because the image size of or.tif is bigger than your screen. It's simply telling you that it is not displaying it at full size. This won't affect histogram equalisation.

The Error with the histogram equalisation is because matlab expects I to be a 2D matrix. Your TIFF file is a 3D matrix, it has width x height x colour.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve with your histogram equalisation, you may need to first convert the image to a grayscale image

```
greyI = rgb2gray( I(:,:,1:3) );
J = histeq( greyI );
```

or to apply histogram equalisation to each of the three colour planes in turn.

```
J = zeros( size( I ) );
J(:,:,1) = histeq( squeeze( I(:,:,1) ) );
J(:,:,2) = histeq( squeeze( I(:,:,2) ) );
J(:,:,3) = histeq( squeeze( I(:,:,3) ) );
% Next line if you have alpha channel
if( size( J, 3 ) == 4 )
    J(:,:,4) = histeq( squeeze( I(:,:,4) ) );
end
```

Comment: you left a typo `==` in the condition. also i guess you don't need `squeeze` in the last line.

Comment: @SanthanSalai - Correct.  `squeeze` is unnecessary here.  The singleton dimensions are being squashed by directly indexing into the third dimension.